# 2d matrix, the translation axis change with rotation :/

Tags: math, matrix, rotation, translation

I have a 2d matrix that stotres the translation and rotation of an element, when I set a rotation to the object, and move the object by using this : 
v is the translation vector

mymatrix.multiply([1, 0, v.x,
          0, 1, v.y])

the up vector is changed, because i combine a rotation with the tanslation. is there a way to translate the object without having to take into account the rotation?

one possibility I thought, was to take into account the actual rotation of the matrix, and counter rotate my vector before applying it to the matrix?

dunnoif this is viable

Comment: The matrix shown above does not have a rotation component. Please show valid code to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

OK found the solution to the problem,

the translation have to be multiplied with the matrix transpose of the objects matrix.

before applying the translation.